# Make background transparent with Image::Magick and Perl

Tags: perl, imagemagick, transparency

I built a Perl script which draws a banner using [Image::Magick](https://metacpan.org/module/Image::Magick).

```
# ... some code
my $icon = Image::Magick->new();
$icon->Set(size => '16x16');
$icon->Transparent(color=>'#010101');
$icon->ReadImage($imagepath);
$full_image->Composite( # small icon 
    image=>$icon,
    compose=>'Over',
    opacity=>'99%',
    x=>'12',
    y=>'62',
);
# ... some code
```

Normally the icon background (`#010101`) should be transparent, but that failed...
any idea why this doesn't work? Or maybe what I could use instead of this Transparent-Method?

**Edit:** Both images are `PNG` files. `Image::Magick` version is 6.7.

Comment: I think you may well have to set the transparent colour *after* you have loaded the image from the file. By the way `$imagepath` shouldn't be in quotes. How do you save `$icon` to a file?

Comment: oh ... in real the $imagepath is `'/var/......'` :D i justed used the variable here :) .. but i forgot to remvoe the single quote :D ... `'$imagepath'` wouldn't work.

oh as u can see i `Composite` it to the final picture and then
`$full_image->Write( $file );` it :D

Comment: **EDIT**: i tried out to change it _after_ the loading :( .. that makes no difference

Answer (score 2):

I haven't really used this module much but I have a couple of ideas :)

1. You are setting the opacity of $full_image to 99%. Wouldn't you want that at a smaller value to make the image transparent?
2. According to [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php) page, you can call a method called opaque:

   > **Opaque** : color=>color name, fill=>color name, channel=>{All, Default,
   >                 Alpha, Black, Blue, CMYK, Cyan, Gray, Green, Index, Magenta, Opacity,
   >                 Red, RGB, Yellow}, invert=>{True, False}
3. I would read the image first, then make the color transparent (just in case):

   ```
   $icon->ReadImage($imagepath);   
   $icon->Transparent(color=>'#010101');
   ```
4. (**Ugly hack**) Run convert as a system command on the image, then load it:

   ```
   my $icon = Image::Magick->new();
   $icon->Set(size => '16x16');
   system("convert -transparent '#010101' not_transp.png transp.png");
   $icon->ReadImage('transp.png');
   $full_image->Composite( # small icon 
       image=>$icon,
       compose=>'Over',
       opacity=>'99%',
       x=>'12',
       y=>'62',
   );
   ```

Comment: to 1. : i tried to set it down, but this is not the point i wanted, its just the opacity itself for the full image. :S ... when its up to 100%, its not shown, same thing with 1% or 0%.                             to 2. : same thing there. i tried the opaque method on the picture. after and before reading the original pic. no difference                 to 3. : i tried this after the comment below my question. no differece :(... but thanks anyway :D

Comment: after EDIT: O.o oh no sorry... thats pretty ugly ;D but it works yeah :D ... but there must be an option with perl itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell ImageMagick to use the Alpha channel.

On the commandline this would be `-alpha On`.

Comment: sorry, but that dont works :(. I set the alphachannel on the image, but there was no difference.